# How to delete line with matching pattern from another file?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, tcl

I want to delete lines in FILE1 contains pattern in FILE2.
How do I do this using shell/bash or Tcl?

For example:

FILE1:

```
This is ECO_01  
This is ECO_02  
This is ECO_03  
This is ECO_04
```

FILE2:

```
ECO_02  
ECO_04
```

Output:

```
This is ECO_01   
This is ECO_03
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

most generic solution will be

```
$ grep -vf file2 file1
```

note that any substring match on any field will count.  If you only restrict to exact match on an exact field (here assumed the last)

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} !($NF in a)' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 2):

In Tcl, you'd load the file of patterns in and use them to then do the filtering. It's probably simplest to keep the main filtering flow going from standard input to standard output; you can redirect those from/to files easily enough. Since you seem to be wanting to use “is pattern a substring of” as a matching rule, you can do that with `string first`, leading to this code:

```
# Load in the patterns from the file named by the first argument
set f [open [lindex $argv 0]]
set patterns [split [string trimright [read $f] \n] \n]
close $f

# Factor out the actual matching
proc matches {theString} {
    global patterns
    foreach pat $patterns {
        # Change the next line to use other matching rules
        if {[string first $pat $theString] >= 0} {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

# Read all input lines and print all non-matching lines
while {[gets stdin line] >= 0} {
    if {![match $line]} {
        puts $line
    }
}
```

I find it helpful to factor out procedures with key bits like “does this line match any of my patterns?” You'd probably call the above code a bit like this:

```
tclsh doFiltering.tcl patterns.txt <input.txt >output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use **sed** command ( as shown below ) to delete the matching lines from FILE1.

**macOS:**

```
for i in `cat FILE2.txt`
do
sed -i '' "/$i/d" FILE1.txt
done
```

**Linux:**

```
for i in `cat FILE2.txt`
do
sed -i '/$i/d' FILE1.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Tcl solution:

```tcl
set fid [open file2 r]
set patterns [lmap line [split [read -nonewline $fid] \n] {string trim $line}]
close $fid

set fid [open file1 r]
set lines [split [read -nonewline $fid] \n]
close $fid

set wanted [lsearch -inline -all -regexp -not $lines [join $patterns "|"]]
puts [join $wanted \n]
```

```
This is ECO_01  
This is ECO_03
```

Ref: [`lsearch` man page](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lsearch.htm)